# Iframe src base64 encoded not working as expected

Tags: php, html, iframe, base64, encode

I'm trying to set an iframe with the src encoded, in this case base64. This is kinda of what i want to do. Note: there's nothing wrong with the link, this is just an example.

```
<?php
$src = "data:text/html;base64,".base64_encode("http://example.com");
?>
<iframe src="<?= $src ?>"        
</iframe>
```

the output is just the src decoded, like a simple echo...how can i do this in a way to show the iframe content as expected?

Comment: `data:` returns (kind of) an object (in your case, a HTML document), so `iframe` displays _that document_. Any reason you want to base64 the url?

Comment: hm ok, so how can i display the content from that object? The reason it that i want to hide some parameters, so actually i dont need to encode all the url, but if i could, it would be better :)

Comment: By `data: base64("http://")`, you actually ask browser to treat that URL as the document _content_ (so you get that URL displayed, instead of the content _pointed by_ that URL). Due to the nature of `data:`, I would say that you can't do what you want, unless you own that `iframe` so you can pass URL like `http://domain/?para=base64()` and in that `iframe` `base64_decode($_GET['para'])`.

Comment: i think that will be the best way, thanks! Actually i own the iframe, and they're both on the same domain, now i think i will face another problem. using    $_GET to get the parameter will not work with the iframe, because this url with the parameter is going to the src of <iframe> while the    $_GET will try to get the parameter from the parent, but ill try first!

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `base64_encode` is a function that requires a *string*, it does not run a command. In this case to get the code (HTML, XML, JPEG, PNG, JavaScript, CSS, etc) you'll need to use something such as cURL:

```
<?php
$curl_connection = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curl_c, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.example.com/');
curl_setopt($curl_c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$code = curl_exec($curl_c);
curl_close($curl_c);

echo '<iframe src="data:text/html;base64,'.base64_encode($code).'"></iframe>';
?>
```